# Color specific excel cells based on match condition in python

Tags: excel, python-2.7

I got an excel sheet with weekly data for number of people

```
Sam    Tony   Michael 
10      34      25
10      22      25
10      22      33
10      22      33
```

Requirement is to compare the rows with first value in their respective column and then color the cells which do not match the first row value in their columns

I have been able to write code to find different values, however unable to color those cells

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook("test1.xlsx")
mysheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
numrows = mysheet.nrows
value = ""
value1 = ""

col = 0
st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;')
st.pattern.pattern_fore_colour = 1
while col < 200:
        value = mysheet.cell(1 , col)
        for y in range(numrows-1):
                y +=1
                value1 = mysheet.cell(y , col)
                value = str(value)
                value1 = str(value1)

                if (value1 != value):
                        <Colour the cell>  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                else:
                        continue
        col +=1
```

Also not sure if the same input sheet's cell colors can be changed or have to create a new one

## EDIT 1:

I tried following, however I am unable to open the file from the format in which python is saving:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlrd import open_workbook
file_path = '/home/zoro/test1.xlsx'
rb = open_workbook(file_path, formatting_info=True)
mysheet = rb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
numrows = mysheet.nrows
numcols = mysheet.ncols
value = ""
value1 = ""
z = 1
col = 0
wb = copy(rb)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;')
st.pattern.pattern_fore_colour = 1
while col < numcols:
        value = mysheet.cell(z , col)
        for y in range(numrows-1):
                y +=1
                value1 = mysheet.cell(y , col)
                value = str(value)
                value1 = str(value1)

                if (value1 != value):
                        w_sheet.write(y,col,value1,st)
                else:
                        continue
        col +=1

wb.save(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the desired result:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlrd import open_workbook
rb = open_workbook('test1.xlsx')
mysheet = rb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
numrows = mysheet.nrows
numcols = mysheet.ncols
value = ""
value1 = ""
col = 0
wb = copy(rb)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;')
st.pattern.pattern_fore_colour = 4
while col < numcols:
        value = mysheet.cell(1 , col)
        for y in range(numrows-1):
                y +=1
                value1 = mysheet.cell(y , col)
                value = str(value)
                value1 = str(value1)

                if (value1 != value):
                        w_sheet.write(y,col,value1,st)
                else:
                        continue
        col +=1

wb.save('output.xls')
```