# Color specific excel rows based on cell value OpenPyXL

Tags: colors, row, cell, openpyxl

I am wondering how to color a row depending on the cell value. I have been using OpenPyXL so far, but I am only able to color a cell and not a row. Below is my code. Can I change it/manage it in order to color rows in my worksheet ? Also, it's not very convenient to use "J3:J5000", but I would prefer to go up to the end of my J column. How could we do that too ?

Sorry for beginners question, but this is my first time in Python ...

```html
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111',end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
ws1.conditional_formatting.add('J3:J5000', CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'],fill=redFill))
```

Comment: I have found something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317596/color-specific-excel-cells-based-on-match-condition-in-python but it's not using OpenPyXl.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
for row in sheet_report['J3':'J5000']:
for cell in row:
    cell.fill = yellowfill
    wb_report.save(report)
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should just be able to reference the column: `J:J` but the logic for this doesn't work at the moment. Internally, Excel always converts column and row ranges to their maximum possible values – 16384 for columns and what should be 1000000 for rows, except that it rounds this up. This is the most reliable way of doing this. So in your case: `J3:J1000000`